# I have an issue like selecting and unselecting four radio buttons in the custom

Tags: java, android

I have an issue like selecting and unselecting four radio buttons in the custom list, button are not in radiogroup, every button in the list but I want to click one button  the setOnCheckChangeListner() works only for the first time below is the code which I have tried.

```
    rbutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            rbutton.setChecked(true);
            rbutton.setTag(maintitle[position]);
            a=rbutton.getTag().toString();
            arrayList2.add(a);


        }else {
            rbutton.setChecked(false);
            arrayList2.remove(rbutton.getTag().toString());

        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you don't have to call `rbutton.setChecked(true);` inside the `onCheckedChanged`

Comment: Bro, there are other components like CheckButton or Switch for single marks, why are you using radiobuttons out of a radiogroup?

Comment: if you are using RadioGroup inside the XML then you do not need to manage in a java file. In RadioGroup, all radio button unchecked by default you want if the user checked one then the other automatically unchecked. you not need to manage in java class all processes execute automatically if you are placing four radio buttons inside the Radio Group.

Comment: no i am not using radiogroup i use customlist and in custom list show 4 item. every item has on radiobutton now I want to select the on radio button in 4 item just on radio click and when submit that show that you select the item is that....

Answer (score 0):

Use OnClickListener if you want to control the click separately

this way:

```
rbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        logd("TAG", "rButton Tapped")
    }
});
```

Comment: i can't understand please explain it